# Fudge didnt set. How to fix without re heating

Tags: chocolate, fudge, sprinkles

I made a simple fudge with white choc and condensed milk. It didn't set. I know the easy answer is put it back in the saucepan and re heat it  but it is coloured 4 different colours and swirled together with sprinkles on top. Re heating it will make it an ugly brown mess.
Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Welcome! Can you [edit] your post with a few details, please? What’s your recipe (ratios and method), how long have you refrigerated your fudge, anything else you can think of? There are different methods of making fudge so  even if we can’t fix this batch (never underestimate the creativity of our users, though), the first step is helping us understand what possibly went wrong.

Comment: In particular, what sort of container is it in/on now? I'd be tempted to reheat it as evenly as possible in that (using an oven) if heat-proof.  There will be some mixing but it might just work, but I like to experiment

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.